# Diagonalization of a transposed square root matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, diagonalization

I'm working through a linear algebra book and in the appendix of the book they state the following,

"The principal square root of $A$ is defined to be
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}}=V D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T$$
where $A$ is a positive semi-definite and symmetric matrix, $D$ is a diagonal matrix and $V$ is an orthogonal matrix. The matrices hold the following,
$$A^{\frac{1}{2}} (A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T=A$$
and
$$(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T A^{\frac{1}{2}}=A$$
provided that $A$ is invertible."

I've tried proving this using the definition of a square root matrix via diagonalization by using
$$
\begin{align}
A^{\frac{1}{2}} A^{\frac{1}{2}}&= (V D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)(V D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T) \\
&=V D^{\frac{1}{2}} (V^TV) D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T \\
&=V D^{\frac{1}{2}}D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T \\
&=VDV^T \\
&=A
\end{align}
$$
I do note that since $A$ is symmetric then $V^T=V^{-1}$ as the proofs above are just modifications of proving the square root of a matrix.
However, I'm having some issue understanding how to implement the transpose properly for either case,

$$
\begin{align}
(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T A^{\frac{1}{2}}&= (V D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)^T(V D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)
\end{align}
$$

So my question is two parts,

1. How does taking the transpose of $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ affect the proof properly? As I believe there is something simple I am missing.
2. Can the same proof be done to show that $A^{-\frac{1}{2}} (A^{-\frac{1}{2}})^T=A^{-1}$ and $(A^{-\frac{1}{2}})^T A^{-\frac{1}{2}}=A^{-1}$?

Thank you

Comment: 1: Compute $(A^\frac12)^T$. 2: Yes (mutatis mutandis), provided $A$ is invertible.

Comment: Thanks Anne, 
I think I am understanding now that since $A$ is symmetric it holds true that $(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T=A^{\frac{1}{2}}$.  Thus using the definition of matrix $A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ from above we have that $(VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)^T=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T$. Thus this allows us to write that  $(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T A^{\frac{1}{2}}=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}D^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T=VDV^T=A$.
For part two, the only thing that changes is that each $D^{\frac{1}{2}}=D^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ with the last line of the proof being $D^{-1}$.

Comment: The beginning of 1. is in the opposite way: $(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T=A^{\frac{1}{2}}$ does not come "magically" from the fact that $A$ is symmetric, but from its definition and from the computation $(VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)^T=...=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T$.

Comment: Hey Anne thank you. I reworked it and took into consideration that we are doing the diagonalization of A. Thus I have the following proof,

$(A^{\frac{1}{2}})^T=(VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T)^T=V^T(D^{\frac{1}{2}})^T(V^T)^T=VD^{\frac{1}{2}}V^T$

Comment: In the preceding step I forgot to change the order of the first and last term after taking the transpose.

Comment: .....Well done!